# Nginx add location details to URL when we stop decoding URL

Tags: nginx

I am accessing a URL which has encode characters

```
http:....../malintha/tel%3A%2B123



   location /gateway/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_read_timeout 5m;
    proxy_send_timeout 5m;
    proxy_pass http://10.1.1.1:9443$request_uri/;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```

I added **$request_uri** at then end of the proxy_pass URL as I have to stop decoding by nginx.

When I configure like this nginx resolve it to (stop decoding but incorrect URL - adding /gateway/)

/gateway/ussd/tel%3A%2B123

but When I remove **$request_uri** it resolve to correct URL (but with decoding)

```
ussd/tel:+123
```

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

use regex to remove /gateway/ from proxied uri

```
location ~ ^/gateway/(.*)$ {
   ...
   proxy_pass http://10.1.1.1:9443/$1/;
}
```

UPD:
According to documentation, URI's get decoded when using URI part at proxy_pass directive. So you should try to change $request_uri to avoid decoding and get rid of /gateway/. Try this

```
location /gateway/ {
    rewrite ^/gateway(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://10.1.1.1:9443;
}
```

Comment: Yes it removes /gateway/ part. But my telephone number is decoded ny nginx when it resolves URL.  got this ---->   /ussd/1.0/outbound/tel:+123

Comment: How to stop this decoding ?

Comment: No luck, stil number decoded. Did you miss anything ? Do we have to append any thing to proxt pass URL ?

Comment: How to make $request_uri to avoid decoding ?